# Bash run sh through screen and output data

Tags: bash, gnu-screen

I'm working on a bash script that will connect to a screen and run another bash file, that bash file will then output a bunch of text on the screen.

So far I'm able to start the screen, but I'm unable to connect to the screen, run a bash file, and then see the output.

Here's what I got so far:

```
SCREEN_NAME="the_screen"

function startScreen(){
    echo "Attempting to Start New Screen..."
    screen -dmS $SCREEN_NAME
    echo "Screen '${SCREEN_NAME}' Started!"
}

function runStartBash(){
    echo "Attempting to Run Script..."
    screen -S $SCREEN_NAME -X stuff 'sh /home/blob/nox/start.sh"^M'
}


startScreen

runStartBash
```

start.sh contains a simple loop to print data. It works on its own but can't figure out how to run it through a screen.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try removing unwanted `"` from `runStartBash()`

```
screen -S $SCREEN_NAME -X stuff 'sh /home/blob/nox/start.sh"^M'
```

Make it as:

```
screen -S $SCREEN_NAME -X stuff 'sh /home/blob/nox/start.sh ^M'
```

then start the script as `'bash scriptname.sh'`

Comment: Wow, didn't even notice that there. Got this working, thanks for the help!